# Gatsby build html content is empty

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I have a website done in Gatsby@2.2.10. When I run `gatsby build` and inspect the generated html, for every page, all I see is an empty div: `<div id="___gatsby"></div`. The html contains the stylesheets, javascript files and everything needed to run the app (which works by the way).

Even if I `curl` the production url, the same div appears and is completely empty. I also tried with javascript disabled and all I get is a blank page. My config contains nothing fancy:

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title      : `MyApp`,
        description: ``,
        author     : ``,
    },
    plugins     : [
        `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `images`,
                path: `${__dirname}/src/static/images`,
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-less`,
            options: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
            },
        },
        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
        `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
            options: {
                fonts: [
                    `Montserrat\:200,400,600,800`,
                ],
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
            options: {
                name            : `MyApp.com`,
                short_name      : `MyApp`,
                start_url       : `/`,
                background_color: `#4DECDB`,
                theme_color     : `#2F57E4`,
                display         : `minimal-ui`,
                icon            : `src/static/images/logo.png`,
            },
        },
        `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
            options: {
                // replace "UA-XXXXXXXXX-X" with your own Tracking ID
                trackingId: 'UA-111111111-16',
            },
        },
        //  last
        'gatsby-plugin-netlify',
    ],
}
```

My `gatbsy-node` file is empty and `gatsby-browser` just loads a stylesheet and a redux store:

```
import wrapWithProvider from './wrap-wit-provider'

import './src/components/layout/styles.less'

export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

Any ideas what I should look for? I wouldn't be that concerned unless Netlify's inability to detect my forms and process them due to non-existing html code.

Comment: I believe it's fine to see empty `<div id="___gatsby"></div>`. React app is generated on the fly and is not present in the static layout. So, what is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Gatsby is a static site generator. It should output static content for search engines. You can test that on another Gatby powered website: `curl https://www.qards.io/a-blog-that-is-100-free-can-serve-any-traffic-and-is-unhackable/ | grep "fully functional website"`

Comment: Have you try follow these steps? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/ It's really hard to tell where the problem is.

Comment: Could you please check my answer? If it doesn't help, then please elaborate a little bit more on the issue.

Comment: I would say its the `wrapWithProvider` function. Can you share what it looks like? It wraps the root element, so you would have to return a component wrapping with argument it was called with

Answer (score 1):

I got here searching for "blank page" on gatsby build, the problem in my case was a silly one, hope it helps someone.

If `public` folder has been modified, or file moved, gatsby will fail. Just deleting entire folder and rebuilding worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything definitive without having access to the code, but if the generated HTML files are empty but the site works, then your page is returning `null` or `undefined` instead of a component when server side rendering, but returning the correct component on the client side.

[The Redux for Gatsby example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-redux/gatsby-ssr.js) and tutorials like [Edward Beazer's blog](https://www.edwardbeazer.com/setting-up-redux-with-gatsbyjs-v2/) will tell you to add a `gatsby-ssr.js` with the same content as `gatsby-browser.js`. Could it be that you have a `gatsby-ssr.js` and it defines a `wrapRootElement` function that returns `null`?

If you do, that will cause the behavior you describe, since it's only run on the server side and would replace every page with an empty page.